# What's the function of the prepositional phrase here?

Tags: prepositions

In school we are learning **about the American Revolution.**

Someone said— It is functioning as the direct object of the present participle — learning.
I think it's the object of preposition....

Comment: "to learn about [something]" is [a phrasal verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/learn-about-of-sth.)

Comment: Well, I have some sympathy, but 'direct object' is about how a sentence is built,not about meaning. The phrase *about the American Revolution* **is** the complement of the verb *learning*, but it is not a direct object. For example, it cannot be passivised: *French is learned from an early age here*, is fine, but _*About the American Revolution is learned from an early age here_ is ungrammatical. The noun phrase *the American Revolution* is the object of the preposition *about* [but *about ... Revolution* isn't the object of a preposition - which preposition could it be the object of?].

Comment: "In school" is the object of the preposition "in."

Comment: @LiceySoremap In the preposition phrase "in school", the word "school" is the object of the preposition "in." But the preposition phrase "in school" is not the object of the preposition "in" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In school we are learning **about the American Revolution**.

I add to what @Araucaria - Not here any more said.

*the American Revolution* is the object of preposition *about*.  The entire preposition phrase,
*about the American Revolution*, is the complement of the verb *learning*, but it is **not** a direct object.

[ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub](https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/essentialsoflinguistics/chapter/8-8-grammatical-roles/) explains further, that if a verb's complement is not a noun phrase or a determiner phrase, then it is not a direct object:

> If a Verb head takes a complement that is some category other than an NP or DP, then that complement phrase does not count as a direct object.